# How to create a virtual host in other partition ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, partitioning, apache2, virtualhost

I have a partition of `/media/ramesh/Backend`. I created a folder in this partition and added a virtual host as follows:

Step 1: I created a conf file by this code `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/reform.lan.conf`

step 2: codes in it-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@reform
        ServerName reform.lan
        ServerAlias www.reform.lan
        DocumentRoot /media/ramesh/Backend/reform

<Directory /media/ramesh/Backend/reform >
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Step 3: And enabled site by `sudo a2ensite reform.lan.conf`

But when I use `http://reform.lan/` I get

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server. error.
```

I can't trigger out the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You must change owner of `/media/ramesh/Backend/reform` as follows:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/ramesh/Backend/reform
```

Comment: sorry I get the same error. Do I need to replace anything in www-data:www-data?

Comment: No you don’t. Virtual host’s root dir needs to be owned by www-data user and group.

Comment: thnks a lot finally your answer helped ma lot. Your answer resolved my issue.

Comment: `www-data` should have also read presmissions for all parent directories.